# War deploy to play

Tags: playframework

Is there some way to get a java war project and deploy on play framework? 
I know that it is possible do the reverse on play.
I want to know if is possible do it automatically without placing the files manually.

Comment: The plugin play2war solves it. https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin =)

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Play is not a servlet container, like Tomcat or JBoss, so you cannot really deploy a war to Play.

Comment: You just repeat what I said.=D